# how can i add dynamic column beside each other in ssrs table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

[image]

the number of `item` column and `NetSale` column are changeable due to the selected period as in the example(from a date and to date)

Answer (score 0):

You could either add a column to the underlying query of the dataset or add a field to the report itself.  For the latter, you would add a new column to the tablix inside the report, then click the field of the tablix and go into its properties and change its value to be calculated based on other fields or parameters in the report.

For a tutorial on how to do this see this Youtube link from Wise Owl (Around 30 mins)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWRV3ist9Fk

or this link from TechBrothersIT (Around 7 minutes)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvGvfKxy1r0

Both have other videos that are useful for learning about SSRS.